# how do i set images at the same bottom level (using just css no js)?

Tags: css, html, flexbox

Thanks for your responses in advance.

i know how te create a responsive product grid if i all pictures have the same height and the same title length using just css properties like `flex display` and `flex-end align` for the children,but when I use images (multiple height) and title for each image (different length for each one), i get this probleme :

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <div class="imgChild row-eq-height">
        <div class="img-slider-parent">
            <div class="container-slider">
                <button class="btn green-btn" type="button">Voir</button>
            </div>
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://placebear.com/200/400">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="product-title">title1</div>
            <div class="product-number">category1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgChild row-eq-height">
        <div class="img-slider-parent">
            <div class="container-slider">
                <button class="btn green-btn" type="button">Voir</button>
            </div>
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://placebear.com/350/400">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="product-title">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
            <div class="product-number">category1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgChild row-eq-height">
        <div class="img-slider-parent">
            <div class="container-slider">
                <button class="btn green-btn" type="button">Voir</button>
            </div>
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://placebear.com/300/400">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="product-title">yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</div>
            <div class="product-number">category1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgChild row-eq-height">
        <div class="img-slider-parent">
            <div class="container-slider">
                <button class="btn green-btn" type="button">Voir</button>
            </div>
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://placebear.com/200/250">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="product-title">title1</div>
            <div class="product-number">category1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgChild row-eq-height">
        <div class="img-slider-parent">
            <div class="container-slider">
                <button class="btn green-btn" type="button">Voir</button>
            </div>
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://placebear.com/200/200">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="product-title">title1</div>
            <div class="product-number">category1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgChild row-eq-height">
        <div class="img-slider-parent">
            <div class="container-slider">
                <button class="btn green-btn" type="button">Voir</button>
            </div>
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://placebear.com/200/100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="product-title">title1</div>
            <div class="product-number">ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.imgContainer {
    width: 100%;
    /* background-color: red;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imgChild {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: flex-end;
    background-color: red;
}

.imgChild > img {
    width: 100%;
}

.product-title,
.product-number {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.product-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 15px;
}


.img-slider-parent {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-slider {
    display: none;
}

.green-btn {
    display: block;
    background: #3DCFB2;
    border-radius: 19px;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
}
.imgSlider {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**You can also find this code at jsfiddle to play with : 
http://jsfiddle.net/ukgqrysr**

Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: please any help or suggestion for any idea.

Comment: You need something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zeevkatz/18puo9em/

Comment: @ZeevKatz sorry noo, i have to set images at same bottom line

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know in advance the size of your text, you can and you want this size of the text to affect other elements that are not related to the current element that contains the text - your simplest (however hardcoded) solution can be to set the exact height of that container. If all of your `text` containers will have the exact same height - you will be able to put the image at the bottom of the parent container and they will all be positioned at the exact same "button" position.

You can set this height using:

```
.imgChild.row-eq-height > div:nth-child(2) {
    height: 55px;
}
```

> This specific value with your existing code gives 3 lines of text.

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fmfouubk/1/

Comment: Thanks, so Thats good but i got some issue when i resize screen : http://hpics.li/879de93 text is injected on top of image

Comment: The problem is that you can't use **fixed** value if you don't know how many lines you might need. This example (with your current structure) will work only if you know how many lines of text you need (as also mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Yeah that's the problem :/

Comment: Well, a voteup on the answer will be nice ;) (even though it doesn't really fix all of your problems). Why do you require a CSS-only solution?

Comment: no i wanna just use css no js please, i know how tu use js process to resolve this issue :)

Comment: I guess you can change the HTML structure or completely change the CSS... I didn't have enough time to check this out but If you know how many lines of text you have the above solution works great (and for smaller screens you can use the `@media` query to set the height for higher value.

Comment: get number of lines of text to set height value of div is not the best solution i guess, the height of the div must be set automatically using just CSS